# How to apply ng-click before page load

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want the "edit" button below to be in the "clicked" stated before the page loads. How can I achieve this?

```
<div class="buttons" ng-show="!rowform.$visible" style="width: 20%">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="rowform.$show()">edit</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeUser($index)">del</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just change the `ng-show` value to `rowform.$visible`? That would make more sense anyway.

Comment: Because all that would do is hide the edit and del buttons on load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new scope property like...

```
$scope.editingIndex = 0;
```

So your ng-show on each edit row will look like `ng-show='editingIndex == $index'`

Initializing the property to 0 will start the first available row off in the editing state (which I think is what you really want anyway).

Then use the scope variable as a mechanism to determine which row is currently editable. If nothing is editable, just set `$scope.editingIndex = -1;` to disable all the edit rows.